# How to order and display json values in list, if some values are not unique and some are unique

Tags: arrays, json, jsonreader

```
{
places: [
{
id: 1,
place:"America",
name: "Robert",
age: "22",
place_lat: "10.017",
place_lon: "76.344"
},
{
id: 1,
place:"America",
name: "Albert",
age: "22",
place_lat: "10.017",
place_lon: "76.344"
},
{
id: 2,
place:"China",
name: "Robert",
age: "22",
place_lat: "10.017",
place_lon: "76.344"
}
,
{
id: 2,
place:"China",
name: "Albert",
age: "20",
place_lat: "10.017",
place_lon: "76.344"
},
{
id: 4,
place:"Paris",
name: "Albert",
age: "20",
place_lat: "10.017",
place_lon: "76.344"
}
],
success: 1

}
```

Using this json values, I want to show this in a list view, My expected result is

**America**
Name:Robert
Age:22
Name:Albert
Age:22

**China**
Name:Robert 
Age:20
Name:Albert 
Age:20

**Paris**
Name:Albert
Age:20

I want to add like this in a list view. But i couldn't make. I got like this in a listview

**America**
Name:Robert
Age:22
**America**
Name:Albert
Age:22

**China**
Name:Robert 
Age:20
**China**
Name:Albert 
Age:20

**Paris**
Name:Albert
Age:20

Answer (score 0):

Add each object to an array list by using a loop. In each loop check whether the array list contain the object or not before adding . Then you will get a unique Array list of items

**Or you can do this by using hash-map (key, value pair) . The key represent the place id and value would be the collection of places**

Answer (score 0):

Since the id is not unique and useless, you can ignore it.

You could parse through the json and create a list beforehand which has all the information. As you loop through each name, add it to an existing country or create a new country (As Ajay said you might want to check for duplicate entries by checking all values).

```
names["America"].Add (new person ("robert", 22) );
names["America"].Add (new person ("albert", 22) );
names["Paris"].Add( new person ("albert", 20) );
```

From such an array/dictionary it will be easier to port the information into the format that you are looking for,